# Issue in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was recently attempting to add interactive `div` tags to my HTML website.

For that purpose, I have used the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div').mouseEnter() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        $(this).animate ({
            height:'+=10px'
        });
    });

    $('div').mouseLeave() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
        $(this).animate({
            height:'-=10px'
        });
    });

});
```

My website loads, but `div`s do not act as required.

Could you please tell me if my code contains any errors?

Here is the html portion:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<title>Dempsey Home</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor=black>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css"/>
<center>
<font>
<a name="TOP">
<h1>Kavanaugh Dempsey</h1>
<hr>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div onclick="location.href='index.html'">
        <br><span><b>Home</b></span></a>
    </div>
    </td>
    </a>

    <td>
    <div onclick="location.href='top5.html'">
        <br><span><b>Top Five</b></span>
    </div>
    </td>

    <td>
    <div onclick="location.href='movies.html'">
        <br><span><b>Movies</b></span>
    </div>
    </td>

    <td>
    <div onclick="location.href='movies.html'">
        <br><span><b>Activities</b></span>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</font>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
div {
    height:70px;
    width:120px;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:#00FFFF;
    background-color:#00FFFF;
    border-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    }
span {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
h1 {
   font-family:Comic Sans MS;
   }
font {
    color:cyan;
    font-family:Comic Sans MS;
    }
```

Comment: What is the id or class name of the div? are you sure you want to be saying $('div')

Comment: There is none, I want all of the divs to be affected

Comment: ok, just checking to make sure, I have been nailed by that before :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the [correct fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4MqU/):

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //`mouseEnter` is `mouseenter` and `mouseLeave` is `mouseleave`
    $('div').mouseenter( function () {  // some wrong was syntax here 
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        $(this).animate ({
            height:'+=10px'
        });
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function () {  // some wrong was syntax here 
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1.0); 
        $(this).animate({
            height:'-=10px'
        });
    });
});
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I adjusted the coding, but it still isn't working, I double checked that I was scripting it properly in the html file as well. Is there any special software that would have to be installed on my computer in order for it to work?

Comment: @user3397648 If you doing it on your local machine, have you linked to the [jQuery file](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js) before you link to the `.js` file?

Comment: @user3397648, did you actually include jQuery to your HTML <head>?

Comment: I included it inside of the body, should I have included it in the <head>? And what do you mean have I linked to the jQuery file? I apologize for my lack of knowledge on this subject, I'm extremely new to this language

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Put it to the <head> before any other <script> tags.

Comment: That didn't do anything, Danek

Comment: I had a look at the fiddle, that didn't do anything :c

Comment: @user3397648 So, can you please update your question and include the code you are using (HTML/JS/CSS). Thank you.

Comment: I updated it, thank you for the time to look at this and help me through my issue

Comment: @user3397648 Having a quick look, did you include the beginning `<html>` tag in your html file?

Comment: Yes at the top, but it didn't copy over, my apologies

Comment: @user3397648 [Who told you it does not work?](http://jsbin.com/tegazave/1/). I copied your whole code over and it works.

Comment: I've checked it on my home computer, saving the html, css, and js files all in the same folder and launching the html file. When I go and scroll over my divs nothing happens, they just remain the same

Comment: @user3397648 I seriously have no idea then.. perhaps check for file name typos